# Pause video recording

Tags: ios, xcode, video-recording

I'm trying to create an application where the user can record video from a camera.
One of the features of this application must be a pause in file recording.

For example:
The user starts recording by pressing the "Start" button. After some time user presses the "Pause" button and video recording is paused. Then user presses the "Resume" button and video continues recording in the same file.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Where is your code so far?

Comment: Hello, thank you for reply,
Unfortunately I have no idea how I can realize this feature(((

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set up an AVCaptureSession and a AVAssetWriter then you can switch the recording on an off with the boolean "isRecording".

```
 BOOL isRecording;

-(void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{
     if(videoWriterInput.readyForMoreMediaData && isRecording) [videoWriterInput appendSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer];
}
```

Comment: Hmmmm... Thank you for your reply,
I'll try this.
As I can see, this logic used for video recording. Can I use this logic to audio recording too?

Comment: Yes, you can add sound. There are several tutorials around, for example http://www.ios-developer.net/iphone-ipad-programmer/development/camera/record-video-with-avcapturesession-2

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply and sorry for delay with answer.
With your recommendation I'm added this logic to the video and audio recording and I have some results.
I'm recorded testing video where you can see how this logic works:
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B1IEde1HB7cUeV9YRGxKaWxGdVk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply and sorry for delay with answer.
With your recommendation I'm added this logic to the video and audio recording and I have some results.
I'm recorded testing video where you can see how this logic works:
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B1IEde1HB7cUeV9YRGxKaWxGdVk/edit?usp=sharing
unfortunately, when I try pause recording, audio record paused and added new buffers near the old buffers, while the video record stretch last video buffer for all pause time...
any idea how fix that?
Thank you.

Comment: It seems to be a little out of sync :) If you use AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor to ad frames to the AVAssetWriter you can set the time on which they should be added, which gives you more control over the timing.

Comment: There's a sample iPhone app that demonstrates exactly this technique at http://www.gdcl.co.uk/2013/02/20/iPhone-Pause.html