# AVCaptureSession Pause and Resume recording

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, avfoundation

I am making a movie app for iOS 5.0 using AVCaptureSession.  I am giving the user ability to start-pause-start-stop recording a movie

The three buttons that I have defined are

- Start Recording
- Stop Recording
- Pause Recording

I am able to successfully start & stop a recording. What I am unable to do is pause a recording and then resume it again. I looked at this question/answer on stack overflow but I have no idea how are they pausing and resuming the video? I did find some other posts here but none of them have any sample code that I can use to try it out. If AVAssetWrtier is the way to go how do you use it with AVCaptureSession?

[ios - Pause video recording](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14748031/ios-pause-video-recording)

[Pause & resume video capture for same file with AVFoundation in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14905892/pause-resume-video-capture-for-same-file-with-avfoundation-in-ios)

Here is my code for three buttons

```
        -(IBAction) makeMovieNow
        {
            NSLog(@"makeMovieNow ...");

[session startRunning];
            [movieFileOutput startRecordingToOutputFileURL:movieURL recordingDelegate:self];

        }

    -(IBAction) makeMovieStop
    {
        NSLog(@"makeMovieStop ...");

        //stop recording
        [session stopRunning];
    }

    -(IBAction) makeMoviePause
    {
        NSLog(@"makeMoviePause ...");

        //pause video??? How?

    }

//********** DID FINISH RECORDING TO OUTPUT FILE AT URL **********
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureFileOutput *)captureOutput
didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL:(NSURL *)outputFileURL
      fromConnections:(NSArray *)connections
                error:(NSError *)error
{

    NSLog(@"didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL - enter");

    BOOL RecordedSuccessfully = YES;
    if ([error code] != noErr)
    {
        NSLog(@"ERROR RECODING MOVIE!!! - enter");

        // A problem occurred: Find out if the recording was successful.
        id value = [[error userInfo] objectForKey:AVErrorRecordingSuccessfullyFinishedKey];
        if (value)
        {
            RecordedSuccessfully = [value boolValue];
        }
    }
    if (RecordedSuccessfully)
    {
        //----- RECORDED SUCESSFULLY -----
        NSLog(@"didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL - success");

        UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(videoPath2, self, nil, nil);    

    }
}
```

Comment: I find it absolutely fascinating that pause recording option is available in MAC apis http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/QuickTime/Reference/QTCaptureFileOutput_Ref/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 3):

There's a sample iPhone at http://www.gdcl.co.uk/2013/02/20/iPhone-Pause.html that does exactly this. It uses a Data Output instead of a Movie File Output so that the data is passed to the app. The app then passes the sample to an AVAssetWriter if recording is enabled, and after a pause/resume, the timestamps are adjusted to remove the pause.

G

Answer (score 1):

I ended up creating two files and merged them together. Here is the sample code and tutorial

http://www.raywenderlich.com/13418/how-to-play-record-edit-videos-in-ios